# Magento2.1 Configurable attributes in cart

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, configurable-product, cart

I want to add configurable products attributes to cart page too.

**Example**: 
T-Shirt `color:red` `size:m` already added to cart by price `100$`,

Now I want to **change attributes on cart** and use `color:green` `size:m` `price:110$`
Also images of each attribute should change.

What should I do?

**More explanation:**

I have below SKU's in a configurable product name A:

- t-shirt size m color red price 100$.
- t-shirt size s color red price 110$.
- t-shirt size m color green price 150$.
- t-shirt size s color green price 90$.

Added **t-shirt size m color red price 100$** to my cart. Now I'm on cart page(**`/checkout/cart`**) and I want to change **t-shirt size m color red price 100$** to  **t-shirt size m color green price 150$**.

I don't want to return back to product page, change attributes add to cart again and remove last SKU. I want to change attributes on cart page.

Comment: It doesn't correct answer, can you add code and path here?

Comment: @ PMPD Could you explain your question in more detail? and try attaching some screenshots and code if it is possible.

Comment: @ChintanKaneriya yeah i edited question and add more explanation on it.

Comment: Anybody doesn't have any idea about this question?

Answer (score 0):

In Magento the products that you can add to the cart are Simple products, Virtual Products, Downloadable Products. Configurable products, Grouped products & Bundle products individually can never/not be added to the cart.

Your question is for the Configurable products So here I am explaining the scenario for that only.

- Configurable product is a collection of simple products it is provided to the customer to show the same type of simple products that is variations of same product.
- These variations are can be based on change in color, change in size, change it length, change in weight etc. depends on which type of products you are selling.
- Now When customer is coming to the configurable product page he/she is selecting the variation option that is different attribute values then appropriate simple product is get loaded their into the value section
- Now when customer clicks on the add to cart button the appropriate simple product is get added to the cart which is visible to you on the cart page.

So here the product we have in our cart is a simple product not a configurable product & changing the attribute values & loading the different product is a feature of configurable product so we can't achieve it here. Other thing is that configurable products are always having the quantity 0 because it always depends on the quantity of the relevant simple products it is never/not considering its own quantity.

Adding a configurable product to the cart will require a very high level customization & also a-lot of changes into the default Magentos Configurable products feature.

For the better understanding of different products in Magento Please [refer this](https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/6-types-product-types-magento-2.html).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I knew about them. just need something like https://inchoo.net/magento/updating-options-of-configurable-product-that-is-already-in-the-cart/ on magento 2.1